# Boto SNS ConnectTimeoutError exception does not execute in Lambda with connectivity issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns, botocore

I have a python Lambda function that publishes to an SNS topic. The Lambda was published in the wrong VPC causing it to lose internet connection, making SNS unreachable. That's fine - easy fix.

The problem is that I want to avoid this timeout issue in the future should any connectivity issue arise again, but the Boto timeout configuration does not work - it continues trying to connect until the Lambda times out.

So, the Lambda, which is in a VPC that is NOT connected to the internet has the following:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ConnectTimeoutError
from botocore.config import Config

# configure client to timeout after 1 second and 1 attempt
config = Config(connect_timeout=1, retries={"max_attempts": 1})
client = boto3.client("sns", config=config)


try:
    client.publish(
        TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:xxxxxxxx:my_topic',
        Message=json.dumps(data),
       )
except ConnectTimeoutError as e:
    print("SNS Publish Timed Out")
```

When I deploy this in the Lambda server with no internet connectivity, **I want the SNS publish to timeout**, have the exception rescued, print the error and move on. **Instead it continues trying to publish until the Lambda times out.** Since this SNS message is not mission critical, I need to be able to ditch it if necessary but allow the process to continue.

When I run this locally and set the connect_timeout down to 0.05 it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you also try with `'mode': 'standard'`? Note that ConnectTimeoutError isn't listed in the [retries documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html).

Comment: @jarmod I have tried with standard mode, still no dice. The ConnectTimeoutError is a botocore exception that is thrown on timeout (I'm able to handle this error succesfuly when running the code locally) https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/exceptions.py#L148

Comment: Could you also try `retries={"total_max_attempts:1}` (which means one attempt and zero retries) and also `tcp_keepalive=True` (probably unhelpful given that you're not actually able to connect).

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the ideas. Unfortunately, this also doesn't work. It seems that,  with this particular improper network arrangement, it doesn't even begin the connection so there is no timeout to rescue. It would be nice to have this failsafe but will have to just move on and always make sure to deploy it properly.  Thanks again.